# Excel Advanced Filter only returns header row

Tags: vba, excel, advanced-filter

I've created the following VBA Advanced Filter subroutine by recording and modifying a macro. The desired objective is that it will filter the table in `Sheet3` by criteria specified in `Sheet5` (or return the entire table if it is run with no criteria), then copy it (without the header row) to the `CopyToRange` in `Sheet5`

```
Sub FilterMe()
'
'   FilterMe Macro

    Sheet3.Range("B4").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheet5.Range("AN3:BT4"), CopyToRange:=Sheet5.Range("D7:AJ7"), Unique:= _
        False

End Sub
```

However, no matter what criteria I enter, it *only* returns the header row.  If I enter no criteria, it returns nothing.

I've confirmed via `Ctrl + Shift + *` that the `CurrentRegion` object it refers to is in fact the entire table and not just the header row.  How do I modify the subroutine to meet my objectives?

Comment: Why are you using `Sheet3.Range("B4")`? I guess you should use the entire table Sheet3 instead, as you want to filter the whole table... And are you placing the headers for criteria correctly?

Comment: How did you define your `Sheet3` variable? I dont see that anywhere. Did you may mean `WorkSheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").CurrentRegion....`

Comment: Also, if you put `Option Explicit` at the very top of your file, it will catch mistakes like this for you.

Comment: @paulinhax but Sheet3 isn't a table, it's a sheet.

Comment: @BraX I've rewritten the code to refer to sheets by their WorkSheets index names, but it hasn't changed anything about how the subroutine works.

Comment: Yes, I mean, when you use `AdvancedFilter` the CurrentRegion is the whole region where you'll get information to filter. So, for example, if the information on `Sheet3` is on range A2:E6 it should be `Sheet3.Range("A2:E6").CurrentRegion` instead of `Sheet3.Range("A2").CurrentRegion`